# How to rotate/spin an animated soft body object

Tags: animation, keyframes, soft-body

Probably there's a easy solution to it, but I cannot manage the following:

These two balls are both Soft Body and are colliding into eachother thanks to a force field. I want to give these balls more of a spinning effect during the animation, but if I do this by keyframing the rotation, it seems to be the soft-body ignores it. Any ideas somebody?
[image]

Comment: The soft body doesn't ignore rotation any more than it ignores any other keyframes-- but the strength with which it responds to keyframed transforms is a function of its "goal" settings, and it may not respond to rotation that is too rapid (because as a physics object, it takes time to reach the rotation, and if that rotation is now at 360 or 0 degrees, then there's no longer any rotation.)  There may be some ways to address what you're after, but we'd need more details, like the timing and strength of the keyframes, and soft body settings.

Answer (score 0):

A work around I found for my specific situation was to animate the camera instead of the soft-bodies. This gave me the desired effect of a more dynamic animation.

I parented an empty to the camera, and keyframed a rotation to that so the camera's pivot point was around the two soft-bodies.

[image: Rotating camera]